# Get xcode 4.5 to warn about new API calls

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, warnings

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676000/is-there-a-way-for-xcode-to-warn-about-new-api-calls) does not appear to work on xcode 4.5. To summarise it, is there a way for XCode to warn about classes, methods and procedures that are only available a later version than the deployment target?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a correct answer inside of the question that you linked too.  With some experimentation, I came up with this (from mattjgalloway's answer):

```
#define __AVAILABILITY_TOO_NEW __attribute__((deprecated("TOO NEW!"))) __attribute__((weak_import))

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_6_0
#undef __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0 __AVAILABILITY_TOO_NEW
#endif
```

Then repeat for all the versions that make sense (i.e. 4.3 and above for Xcode 4.5).  The `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` macro will check the deployment target.

Comment: +1 for such a brilliantly filthy precompiler hack. Repeat the body of this for iOS 5 and iOS 6 warnings if you're an unfortunate sod who still has to support iOS 4.

Comment: Very nice.  It doesn't warn against everything, though.  If I have Autolaypout turned on in my XIBs, there will be a runtime crash on an old SDK.

Comment: Sadly, it does not warn for everything. I get a warning for `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` but not for `(NSString *)capitalizedStringWithLocale:(NSLocale *)locale` which are both new in iOS 6.0.

Comment: Not working for me in Xcode 4.5.2; it doesn't warn about -application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: when deploying to iOS 5.1 (base SDK is "latest").

Comment: @randallmeadows Are you calling it directly, or just implementing it?

Comment: @elpsk That method is marked just fine for me so you must have made an error setting it up.  Trying putting it into the PCH file right after the `#import <Availability.h>` line.

Comment: This no longer works for me in Xcode 5 and iOS 7 -- anybody confirm?

Comment: Well for one thing, you need to add a reference to the iOS 7 macro first.  Other than that, I don't have that Xcode so I can't confirm.  @Jeff

Comment: Yup, I've changed all the "_6_0" to "_7_0".  I think it has something to do with a compiler flag -- based on this comment in CFAvailability.h: "... compilers targeting iOS which support attribute_availability_with_message".  But I'm really lost in all those macros.

Comment: There are some new macros and changes in the way they are used that prevents this to work when using the iOS 7 SDK (and thus when using Xcode 5).

Comment: Created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111934/get-xcode-5-to-warn-about-new-api-calls

Answer (score 0):

This tool can do the job of finding too new API calls in your project: http://www.deploymateapp.com/