# Is there a way to find methods in my code which won't run on previous versions of iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, compatibility

I had a problem with the latest release of my app, where iOS 5 users said it was crashing. I quickly discovered the problem to be with using an iOS 6 method. I didn't realise this method was a new one. I was wondering if there was a way to quickly check my code (without doing it method-by-method) to make sure all code is compatible with previous versions of iOS?

Comment: Run on iOS5 simulator/device

Comment: I will pimp my own previous answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632834/get-xcode-4-5-to-warn-about-new-api-calls/12633309#12633309

Answer (score 1):

You should test your app on iPhone/iPad 5.0 simulator. I think they are not available by default XCode 4.6 onwards, but you can download them from: `Preferences` > `Downloads` > `Components`.

Edit: It seems like XCode doesn't warn about new APIs in your code. There a workaround described in this answer: [Get xcode 4.5 to warn about new API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632834/get-xcode-4-5-to-warn-about-new-api-calls/12633309#12633309) -

```
#define __AVAILABILITY_TOO_NEW __attribute__((deprecated("TOO NEW!"))) __attribute__((weak_import))

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_6_0
#undef __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0 __AVAILABILITY_TOO_NEW
#endif
```

Comment: I've done that now - it'd just be nice to know without having to test out every possible scenario on a previous version of iOS.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem - you need to set `Base SDK` to `5.0` (or the minimum version you want to support). The compiler will then throw errors (or warnings?) for unsupported APIs.

Comment: If only it were that easy ;)

Comment: Just saw your answer, will delete this and get off SO now.