# Xcode 7: Warnings when API version is higher than target version?

Tags: ios, warnings, xcode7, compiler-warnings

**Problem:**
Current Base SDK is 9.1. My project Target Version is 7.0.
Xcode 7 doesn't show any warnings when new API is used. It means that when I use API with version > 7.0, then app crashes on devices with iOS 7.0.
I believe that it's impossible to remember availability characteristics for every method and class in SDK.
Manual checking for methods availability isn't very convenient way as well.
So I am looking for automatic tool which will warn me about new API usage.

**What I tried:**
I found a lot of similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676000/is-there-a-way-for-xcode-to-warn-about-new-api-calls/8919108#8919108), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632834/get-xcode-4-5-to-warn-about-new-api-calls?lq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111934/get-xcode-5-to-warn-about-new-api-calls?lq=1)). But all of them are outdated (2010 - 2013), so no one solution works in Xcode 7.

**Question:**
Is there any way to show warning for new API usage in Xcode 7?

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for something similar.

What I found were two options:

1. Deploymate. This is an app that does static code analysis and searches for uses of APIs introduced after your minimum target iOS version.
   [Deploymate](http://www.deploymateapp.com)
2. Making the compiler create deprecated warnings for uses of APIs that were not yet existent in the target iOS version. [You can read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111934/get-xcode-5-to-warn-about-new-api-calls)

We are going with option 1.