# How to detect if I am accessing iOS6-only methods?

Tags: ios, ios6, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way for XCode to warn about new API calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676000/is-there-a-way-for-xcode-to-warn-about-new-api-calls)

I'm building an app that will support iOS 4.3 through iOS 6.x. However, I unknowingly used a method that is marked **__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_6_0)**. This means that the selector does not exist in previous versions of iOS.

Of course, when I tested my code on an iOS 5.x device, the app crashed. I figured out what was going on, and inserted a **respondsToSelector** check, and default to the "iOS 4.x way" of doing things when it fails this check.

How can I prevent these bugs in the future? Is there a compile-time way to **figure out that I am accessing iOS-6-only methods**, so that I can add appropriate iOS feature-checks?

I don't want to accidentally ship a product that works fine on my iOS6 devices, only to have it fail on someone's iOS4.3 device, because the selector does not exist.

Comment: Generally it says in the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919108/208989

Download this header: https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Utilities/MJGAvailability.h

And put the following at the top of your .pch file:

```
#define __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED __IPHONE_4_3
#import "MJGAvailability.h"
```