# Xcode selector availability check

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, selector

Is there a way to check the whole xcode project for selectors that are available only for iOS7/8 versions? I need this to be sure my app wont crash randomly on iOS6 for example, because of selector that is only available on ios7 or 8.

Comment: Any API used in iOS 7 is fine under iOS 8. You only need to check that you guard against iOS 8 APIs when running under iOS 7.

Comment: @rmaddy i know, but say, i want to check if my app works fine on ios7, so i need to find all selectors in code, that are only appeared in ios8.

Comment: Xcode has no such feature. You could compile your project with Xcode 5.1 and see where all the errors are. Then make sure the problem code is properly wrapped with appropriate runtime checks. And of course you should fully test your app on a device running iOS 7 (and 8).

Comment: @rmaddy i guess downloading and older xcode version is the only option for this :( Thanks for your help

Comment: Purchase Deploymate (http://www.deploymateapp.com), and at only $19.99 can be a life saver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way for XCode to warn about new API calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676000/is-there-a-way-for-xcode-to-warn-about-new-api-calls)