# Make Xcode/compiler warn when using CocoaTouch API functionality not compatible with deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode

I/we have a project with base SDK 8 but deployment target 7.1.

Somewhere, someone then used `NSCalendar`'s `compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:`, which was added in iOS 8.0, which caused the app to crash AFTER QA, after having been submitted to the App Store and after review. :(

I was wondering if there is a way to get Xcode/the compiler to warn on such API-usages. Or at least when running `Analyze` in Xcode.

This post [How to use xcode compiler warnings to determine minimum IOS deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688333/how-to-use-xcode-compiler-warnings-to-determine-minimum-ios-deployment-target) I found is quite old. I was wondering if there is an easier way than manually running against older versions than base SDK.

Comment: Your only real option is to change your Base SDK to iOS 7.1 (probably using an older version of Xcode) and see what errors you get. Of course the best solution is to always test your app on a device (or a simulator) using every version of iOS your app supports.

Comment: I remember there were tools exactly doing this job, for example [DeployMate](http://www.deploymateapp.com/). For DeployMate, it looks it's abandoned, not sure if it still works, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way for XCode to warn about new API calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676000/is-there-a-way-for-xcode-to-warn-about-new-api-calls)