# Finding instances of sdk usage outside the deployment target

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk, deployment-target

I'm trying to build an automated test to check that methods called outside of the current deployment target are handled correctly.  Here's a concrete example:

My app is set to use the Mac OS X 10.8 sdk and the deployment target is set to 10.6.

I often use the setTimingFunciton: method.  It was introduced in 10.7.

[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];

In most cases I correctly bounded this method call with a check to ensure the method exists or that the OS was the correct version or later.  But I missed one.  And it's in a rarely executed code path, so even beta testing didn't notice it.  It only came back to bite me much later.

I'd like to build an automated way to test for things like this that can be deployed on an integration server or other such scripted regression test.  It seemed like something there must be a way to check for automatically.

Recompiling with the 10.6 sdk unfortunately results in many errors, most due to "modern obj-c".  These, of course, are not errors when using the 10.8 sdk.  Being careful, I can pick through the errors and find the method calls -- but that's overly complicated and manual.

Does anyone know of a way to statically check these sorts of things that doesn't involve a human picking through hundreds of lines of false-errors?

P.S.  I've read this:  [How to check if not available methods are used if deployment target < base sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437510/how-to-check-if-not-available-methods-are-used-if-deployment-target-base-sdk)
Which recommends another manual flow for digging through them.  The problem is, the human method failed me.  I missed one.  I'd like something a bit more certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993138/1313863) and it has worked great. Totally automatic and it doesn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. undef and redefine the availability macros so they contain something that Clang will object to but will otherwise not affect program flow. Run Clang.